Is there a blank icon in Flutter?
Sometimes, it can be useful to show nothing where an icon would normally be, while using the same amount of space (such as in a list where only some items have icons).
Does Flutter let you do this easily?

The Icon widget allows setting the icon to null, which achieves the desired behaviour.
From the docs:

The icon can be null, in which case the widget will render as an empty space of the specified size.

For example, with a nullable widget myIcon:
myIcon ?? const Icon(null)


Another solution is to use the Visibility widget, which allows you to hide any widget based on a straightforward condition
 Visibility(
            visible: false, // This will occupy space but not show the icon
            child: Icon(Icons.star),
          ),

